# Redis search SchemaFieldTypes.VECTOR

Tags: vector, redis, artificial-intelligence, embedding

Could someone give me source where I could read Redis documentation.
Or how can explain what is SchemaFieldTypes.VECTOR and how to work with it, because when I'm trying to pass there an embedding generated by ada model (array of floats) it trows

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\search\dist\commands\index.js:231:82
    at pushArgumentsWithLength (C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\search\dist\commands\index.js:163:5)
    at pushSchema (C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\search\dist\commands\index.js:230:17)
    at Object.transformArguments (C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\search\dist\commands\CREATE.js:53:23)
    at transformCommandArguments (C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:72:23)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:187:88)
    at Object.Commander.<computed>.<computed> [as create] (C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:58:33)
    at C:\Users\lutsky\Documents\projects\tests\redis-stack\src\index.ts:244:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

This page returns 404
https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/reference/vectors
same as many others on this domain